# how to start a thread when django runserver?

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I want to start a thread when django project runserver successfully.
where can I put the create-thread-and-start code? Is there any hook for the django runserver?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844570/web-application-background-processes-newbie-design-question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081340/how-do-you-do-something-after-you-render-the-view-django, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986060/where-should-i-place-the-one-time-operation-operation-in-the-django-framework

Answer (score 7):

Why would you want to do that? runserver is for development only, it should never be used in production. And if you're running via Apache, it should manage threads/processes for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the above answer, you probably don't want to do this. Runserver should be used for development only. Once you deploy, you'll want to move to Apache/WSGI. On my dev machine (where I do use runserver), I usually throw it in a screen session, so it doesn't get in the way, but I can pull it back up if I need to see a traceback.