# Django: can functions within views run continuously even as other requests are made?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a function that, when called, will extract information from an external source at irregular (and undefined) intervals. This data will then be placed in a database for later retrieval. I want this to be then running in the background even as other page requests are made. Is this possible?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but you probably want to give some more information... Why do you want to run this function from within a view for one...
What's the problem you were trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to django, and I didn't know that you could run functions outside of views. How would you call them in that case? Edit: actually, it would be better for it to run within a view so that I could call it with an http request.

Comment: If it's a function you can call it from any Python code, you just import module, then call module.yourfn()

*why* is it better to call from a HTTP request - what's the context?

Comment: The connection to the external data source would need to be instantiated when the page is loaded, so I guess that makes it necessary to have it within a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run a Django function outside the request/response cycle is to implement it as a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/), which you can then set to run periodically using `cron`.

If you're already using it, [`celery` supports periodic tasks using `celerybeat`](http://celery.github.com/celery/tutorials/clickcounter.html), but this requires [configuring and running the `celerybeat` daemon](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), which can be a headache. Celery also supports long-running tasks (things started in a view, but completing in their own time), as described in your question title.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to give 'celery' a go - it looks like it'll do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to need the function to be called when a page is loaded, you can put it inside your view as

```
def my_view(request):
    #Call the long running function
    long_running_function()
    #Do view logic and return
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

To handle the `long_running_function` you could use `celery` and create a `tasks.py` which implements your external data source logic. Creating tasks, adding to the queue and configuring `celery` is summarized [here](http://mathematism.com/2010/02/16/message-queues-django-and-celery-quick-start/)

If you just need a simpler solution for trying it out, take a look at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

A very similar answer here [Django: start a process in a background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381164/django-start-a-process-in-a-background-thread)

Comment: Thanks very much - 'celery' looks perfect for this.